# DocBook tag for @since?

Tags: versioning, javadoc, docbook, docbook-5

Does the DocBook standard contain any elements that are equivalent to the JavaDoc @since tag?

I'm specifically trying to do this in a "refentry" element, but nothing seems appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite certain that there is no semantic equivalent of the Javadoc `@since` tag. DocBook's [`<refentry>`](http://docbook.org/tdg5/en/html/refentry.html) is modeled on man pages, and there is no specific markup for this purpose in groff (man macros) either, AFAIK. For example, The [mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) man page has several "since" annotations that are simply included as follows in the groff source:

```
.BR MAP_32BIT " (since Linux 2.4.20, 2.6)"
```

[dbdoclet](http://www.dbdoclet.org/projects/dbdoclet/index.html) is tool that converts Javadoc to DocBook XML. For a class that has a `@since` tag in its top-level documentation comment, it outputs markup like this:

```
<variablelist>
    <varlistentry>
      <term><emphasis>Since</emphasis></term>
      <listitem>
        <para><simplelist type="inline"><member>January 8, 2014</member></simplelist></para>
      </listitem>
    </varlistentry>
</variablelist>
```

There is nothing "wrong" with this, but it is rather verbose.

---

I suggest keeping it simple. Just add the "since" information to whatever markup container that seems appropriate. For example:

- The title of a refsection:

  ```
  <refsection>
     <title>TITLE HERE (since release X.Y.Z)</title>
      ...
  </refsection>
  ```
- A paragraph (perhaps with a `role` attribute):

  ```
  <para role="since">Since release X.Y.Z</para>
  ```

Comment: Yes, this is what I ultimately ended up doing.  It's not semantic which bugs me, but I can live with it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the tag [revhistory](http://www.docbook.org/tdg5/en/html/revhistory.html) with sub tag [revision](http://www.docbook.org/tdg5/en/html/revision.html), can be used for it.

Below a small example to capture the idea:

```
<section  title="Section with history information">
  <revhistory>
    <revision>
      <revnumber>0.9</revnumber>
      <date>1996-12-11</date>
    </revision>
  </revhistory>

  <para>
    <revhistory>
      <revision>
        <revnumber>0.8</revnumber>
        <date>1996-11-11</date>
      </revision>
    </revhistory>
    This paragraph has it's own revision history.
  </para>
</section>
```

Comment: I tried this approach, but it's really overkill.  There are some projects that convert JavaDoc to DocBook, I think I might look and see what they do.